# fetch returns some HTML looking stuff rather then the stuff I fetched

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server, vite, fetch-api

so I am very new to web development and after learning the basics I wated to learn a framework so I chose vue and run it with vite
created a project with `npm init vue@latest` witch setups vue with vite and it works great the big problem for me is I need to acess some JSON file trough fetch but when I use fetch it returns some HTML looking code like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js?t=1710967198517"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

rather than the actuall JSON file

the code that that I am running is

```js
fetch(path/to/my/file.json).then((p) => p.json())
```

the thing is p is equal to the HTML code above not the the json string I am tring to fetch

I am not sure why this is but I think because my website is running on a localhost server because web URL's work fine it can't just access my local files trough a simple path my theory is I need to somehow bundle static file with vite but can't find info on how

also don't tell me to import the file with import because this would help in other contexts but in my I am using a library that takes in a path or a URL and does the fetch so I can't just import the JSON I have to fetch it

Comment: what fetch?  show your code please.  what you say you've received is just the index file to your app.

Comment: Please include the code that makes the request and the location of this JSON file within your project. At a guess, you're not getting the URL correctly

Comment: @yoduh no that is not my index.html (even though it kinda looks simularly) that is what the fetch return to me I can't really provide code since I didn't write it and it is in a library just imagine I use 
fetch("path/to/my/flie.json")
and this returns the HTML code provided rather then the JSON thing I need

Comment: if it's a third party library then you should consult the author.  no one can tell you how a library works without even knowing what the library is.

Comment: That is clearly not the code you're using given it's not valid JS. Again, [edit] your question with your **real code** and also specify the location of the JSON file within your project

Comment: @yoduh I added a line for you in the question so you can see what code the library is running because the problem is not in the library it is that the fetch after resolving the promise returns a string containing HTML code rather then JSON I tried to simplify the question it but I listen to criticism and added the line of code where the problem happens

Comment: If you get HTML when you're fetching "not html", then _**the number one**_ reason is because you're asking for a nonexistent URL and what you actually got back is the server's 404 page, so: open dev toosl, select the "network" tab, and look at what it reports is happening with your `fetch()` call's network request.

Comment: @Phil the location of the file is in my assets folder in the src directory of the project

Answer (score 1):

With Vite, bundled static file URLs can be handled in three ways...

1. Using an [explicit URL import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#explicit-url-imports)
2. Using the [public directory](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#the-public-directory)
3. Creating an `import.meta.url` [relative URL](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#new-url-url-import-meta-url)

Normally, JSON files are imported and handled as content during the build phase. To use one in `fetch()`, you want a URL instead.

#### Explicit URL import

```js
import jsonUrl from './relative/path/to/my/file.json?url'; //  note the ?url suffix

fetch(jsonUrl).then((p) => p.json());
```

#### Public directory

Put your file in `public/path/to/my/file.json` and use an absolute URL

```js
fetch('/path/to/my/file.json').then((p) => p.json());
```

#### Module relative URL

```js
const jsonUrl = new URL('./relative/path/to/my/file.json', import.meta.url).href;

fetch(jsonUrl).then((p) => p.json());
```

Comment: I tried the first thing and it seems to work something is giving me an error but that seems to be a problem with the library and not this so thanks if I discover it was still a problem with this I may tag you to ask but probably not again thank